# rspec class_double method not called

Tags: ruby, rspec

I would like to mock an external library (Poseidon)

below is the class i want to test. But I don't want to call Poseidon::Producer.new

```
class KafkaSender < DefaultSender
  def initialize(client)
    hosts = ["#{client}-kafka.pro.hupi.loc:9092"]
    @producer = Poseidon::Producer.new(hosts, "catchbox_api")
  end

  def send(message)
    @producer.send_messages([Poseidon::MessageToSend.new(message.topic, message.to_json)])
  end
end
```

my test

```
require "spec_helper"

describe KafkaSender do
  describe "send message" do
    it "should send a message" do
      poseidon_producer_class = class_double("Poseidon::Producer", new: nil)

      expect(poseidon_producer_class).to receive(:new).with(["test-kafka.pro.hupi.loc:9092"], "catchbox_api")
      KafkaSender.new("test")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the mock directly on the main class like this:

```
expect(Poseidon::Producer).to receive(:new).with(["test-kafka.pro.hupi.loc:9092"], "catchbox_api")
```